# What is the difference between 2 sql queries

Tags: sql

Is there any difference between these 2 quesries? This is from test and one asnwer is right and accordingly another wrong. For me, both are valid and similar.

```
B. SELECT Cust_No, Cust_Name, Emp_Name, Emp_Loc FROM
Customers, Employees WHERE Customers.Sales_Rep_No =
Employees.Sales_Rep_No;

C. SELECT Cust_No, Cust_Name, Emp_Name, Emp_Loc FROM
Customers, Employees WHERE Employees.Sales_Rep_No =
Customers.Sales_Rep_No;
```

Comment: One is prepended with "B. " and the other with "C. ".  The order of the comparison is reversed.  And neither use proper explicit `join` syntax or aliases on columns in the `select`.  Both are equally bad, but should produce the same results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, they differ in their `WHERE`-clauses, but everything else (the Tables joined, the columns retrieved, is the same, and they also should really produce the same result):

`WHERE Customers.Sales_Rep_No = Employees.Sales_Rep_No;`

`WHERE Employees.Sales_Rep_No = Customers.Sales_Rep_No;`

Comment: How does this matter?

Comment: @Tigran it should not :)

Answer (score -1):

There is no functional difference whatsoever.

Comment: This answer would be more correct if you stated that there was no _functional_ difference and explained why that was.

Comment: Is equality not commutative in SQL?